# App Screen relative to mobile screen Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

while I work on website and I would like converted to android app

but when building app using Phonegap only shows half of website and other half does not appear

my website:

[image]

in mobile "Depend on mobile screen":

[image]

How I can Solve this bug please.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework for this or just hand coding?

I suspect this is related to the viewport. Do you have anything like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in your app?